# How to convert UIView as UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, cgcontext

I am taking screenshot image from currentview.but i want to set frame….don't want to convert  fullview as image.I gave frame size..but it takes always
Image as fullview..any help please?

```
            CGRect rectt = CGRectMake(100, 150,150,200);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectt.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectt];
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use this subClass:

```
// code to use the capture:
    // in .h : #import "CaptureView.h"
    CaptureView *cloneView = [[CaptureView alloc] initWithView:scrollView ];
    [scrollView addSubview:cloneView];
```

with this files code

for CaptureView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>


@interface CaptureView : UIView {
@private
    UIImage *_imageCapture;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageCapture;

// Init
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;

@end
```

for CaptureView.m:

```
#import "CaptureView.h"

// Private
@interface CaptureView (/* Private */)
- (void)settingImageFromView:(UIView *)view;
@end

// Public
@implementation CaptureView

@synthesize imageCapture = _imageCapture;

// Standard
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

// Init
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view {
//    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:[view frame]])) {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0,150,200)])) {
        // Initialization code.
        [self settingImageFromView:view];
    }
    return self;  
}


- (void)settingImageFromView:(UIView *)view {
//    CGRect rect = [view bounds];  
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 150,150,200);  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);  
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();  
    [view.layer renderInContext:context];  
    UIImage *imageCaptureRect;

    imageCaptureRect = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    _imageCapture = imageCaptureRect;
//    _imageCapture = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
//    [_imageCapture retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code.
    CGPoint accPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [_imageCapture drawAtPoint:accPoint];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [_imageCapture release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: This code works really well. One small improvement is to automatically read the source UIView's width & height:


    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);

Comment: this crashes like a charm

Answer (score 0):

quartz might help you... look at [creating image from part of image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBBGCII)....
its not a direct solution to your question, but i think you'll be able to tweak it to fit your needs..